# Yii2 организация почтового клиента

Tags: yii2, email

Приветствую всех! Уже достаточно долго пытаюсь найти информацию по поводу отправки и получения почты. С отправкой то все понятно,а вот получение письма покрыто мраком и не понято что и как. Не понятно два аспекта например есть домен site.ru хочу чтоб на адрес email@site.ru пришла почта, не знаю что и как кофигурировать. Можно ли сохранить письмо в бд например mysql. Или есть другая концепция в организации почтового клиента?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый эффективный вариант - это привязать какой-то  почтовик. Яндекс почта для домена разве плохо? Отличный функционал, антиспам и прочие фичи уже готовы, проверены и оптимизированы.